# How do you get PowerShell to "see" .NET enum values?

Tags: powershell

I'm slowly teaching myself PowerShell and I'm completely baffled by enums.  To my understanding, they're just a collection of friendly names for what are really integer values.  Okay, ... that's great ... but how do you get PowerShell to actually "see" them?

Example:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
$form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Image Viewer"
$form.Width = $img.Size.Width;
$form.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
$pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

This would be great if PowerShell had any clue what "PictrueBoxSizeMode.StretchImage" was.
It's a numeric value -- I know that -- you know that -- how do I get PowerShell to know that?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: `[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage`

Comment: You need the namespace, just like any other type.

Comment: `$pictureBox.SizeMode = 'StretchImage'`

Comment: Bingo on comment #1.  Thank you.  "Just like any other type" would help if this weren't the first "type" I had to deal with.  Just learning.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basic:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode].GetEnumNames()
```

Advanced (names along with their numeric equivalents):

```
[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode])|
    ForEach-Object {"{0} {1}" -f 
        [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::$_.value__, $_ }
```

Also compare `Get-EnumValue` function (custom cmdlet) in my answer to [Getting enum values of Pseudo-Enum classes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146938/88771) at *Code Review*.

**Edit**

All above code containing `[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]` run in `powershell_ise`. Unfortunately, `powershell` raises *`TypeNotFound`* error:

```
PS D:\PShell> [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded. At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

We need to renew a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` namespace; some sources advise renewing a reference to `System.Drawing` as well:

```
PS D:\PShell> [void] (Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms -PassThru)
PS D:\PShell> [void] (Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing -PassThru)
PS D:\PShell> [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage
StretchImage
PS D:\PShell> [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage.value__
1
PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: Yep, I know what the allowed values *are* - I just can't get PowerShell to turn "StretchImage" into whatever numeric value it's supposed to be.